# Protect Node JS code on apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an AngularJS app combined with a REST-service in Node JS.

I have two folders for each

-Client (Angular JS)

-Backend (Node JS)

I have deployed it on an Apache server. Have made a proxy for Node so api/* is redirected from port 8080 to 3000.

So both these folders are placed in the var/www folder. Problem is you can access mydomain.com/backend/routes/api.js. And there you can see my database login and password. Not a good idea so I removed it. How do I protect this information?

Comment: Are you asking, how to configure Apache and set what is public?

Comment: What is the reason for storing your node.js code in apache public directory?

Comment: Well I started of on my dev machine and it worked there. Didn't think of production mode. Is there any best practice where to put the node js code? Guess I need alot of configuration if I put it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the following `.htaccess` file in var/www/backend:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

If you are running Apache 2.4 (or later), you should use:

```
Require all denied
```

You could also restrict access to the backend folder itself (file system permissions) or move the folder.

Comment: What chmod is suitable for the backend folder?

Comment: Depends on your setup. Who is the owner? Which user is your "apache user" and which user executes the node server?